# How can I make it really easy for people to test my app?

Tags: android, testing

I'm thinking about sending my apk to a few willing friends to have them help test my app. Some of them are developers, some are not. I would like to make it extremely easy for them to be able to send me a logcat of a crash.

I suppose I could give them a zip with a batch file, adb, and whatever adb needs to run. The batch could use adb to get a filtered logcat. However, I don't know much about logcat's command line flags. What do I need to know about logcat to make this happen? I'm not even sure this is the best approach. This requires them to have their drivers installed and working and android debugging on... Things that some of my friends probably wouldn't do.

I think I could add my app to the market with a beta build, but this isn't something I've ever done before. Would using the Android Market to distribute the beta allow me to knit-pick my friends and only allow them to get my app? Will they be able to send me feedback if they do this?

Are there other approaches I don't know of? I would love if there's an on-device solution that doesn't require them to plug into a computer or have a rooted device.

Comment: Check for Testflight....

Comment: Testflight, HockeyApp, theres lots of options.

Comment: Testflight no longer supports Android but yes, there are many other testing platforms. Crashlytics is one I know of.

Answer (score 2):

I think Google Play Testing is okay for your. You can give access to Google+ Group (only your friends) or ony to several email addresses. For example, you can collect feedback in group. For more details check this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en
I think it's really the most easiest solution.

Comment: +1 easiest solution for the friends, as crash logs will be sent automatically.